# how get data from c language

Tags: ios, clang, midi

below is the c method i am getting notetype and notenumber i want to show it on the label.
actually i am playing a midi file below method return midi file data but in clang method but i want to show it on the label.

```
static void MyMIDIReadProc(const MIDIPacketList *pktlist,
                           void *refCon,
                           void *connRefCon) {


    AudioUnit *player = (AudioUnit*) refCon;

    MIDIPacket *packet = (MIDIPacket *)pktlist->packet;
    for (int i=0; i < pktlist->numPackets; i++) {
        Byte midiStatus = packet->data[0];
        Byte midiCommand = midiStatus >> 4;


        if (midiCommand == 0x09) {
            Byte note = packet->data[1] & 0x7F;
            Byte velocity = packet->data[2] & 0x7F;

            int noteNumber = ((int) note) % 12;

            NSString *noteType;
            switch (noteNumber) {

                case 0:
                    noteType = @"C";
                    break;
                case 1:
                    noteType = @"C#";
                    break;
                case 2:
                    noteType = @"D";
                    break;
                case 3:
                    noteType = @"D#";
                    break;
                case 4:
                    noteType = @"E";
                    break;
                case 5:
                    noteType = @"F";
                    break;
                case 6:
                    noteType = @"F#";
                    break;
                case 7:
                    noteType = @"G";
                    break;
                case 8:
                    noteType = @"G#";
                    break;
                case 9:
                    noteType = @"A";
                    break;
                case 10:
                    noteType = @"Bb";
                    break;
                case 11:
                    noteType = @"B";
                    break;
                default:
                    break;
            }

            NSLog(@"noteType : noteNumber %@",[noteType stringByAppendingFormat:[NSString stringWithFormat:@": %i", noteNumber]]);
            ViewController* audio = (__bridge ViewController*)refCon;
            [audio.self.noteDisplayLabel setText:@"sdasd"];
           audio.test_messages = @"sdsadsa";
            [audio labelText:@"asdasdas"];
            NSLog(@"%@", audio.test_messages);
            OSStatus result = noErr;
          //    result = MusicDeviceMIDIEvent (player, midiStatus, note, velocity, 0);
        }
        packet = MIDIPacketNext(packet);
    }
}
```

Comment: What does the above method produce? Are you able to get the notes printed?

Comment: And the function above is Objective-C by the way, not C :)

Comment: Krumelur, technically it is a C function with Objective C objects within... and thus would need to be compiled by the ObjC++ compiler.   But we digress, eh ;)

Answer (score 0):

Are your NSLog Messages working?  It looks as if they should be.

It is not a good practice (and may even have problems) setting your view from the MIDI Read Proc, as this is a realtime callback and you don't want to spend time writing to a UI in this place.

Better if you push your events somewhere (like an array) and send a notification to your View Controller (with the array object) at the end function.  You want to return quickly from this function.

Answer (score 0):

I also used this piece of code in my and adapted it to show the note on a label using NSNotification.

```
static NSString* kNAMIDINoteOnNotification = @"kNAMIDINoteOnNotification";
static NSString* kNAMIDI_Note = @"kNAMIDI_Note";
```

...

add this after the case statements

```
NSMutableDictionary* info = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];
[info setObject:[NSNumber numberWithInteger:note] forKey:kNAMIDI_Note];
NSNotification* notification = [NSNotification notificationWithName:kNAMIDINoteOnNotification object:nil userInfo:info];
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotification:notification];
```

add this in your view controller which displays the notes to monitor for notification

```
// notification to monitor for incoming midi note events
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(log:) name:@"kNAMIDINoteOnNotification" object:nil];


- (void)log:(NSNotification *)notification
{

    [NSThread isMainThread];

    NSDictionary* info = notification.userInfo;


    NSNumber *note;
    note = [info objectForKey:kNAMIDI_Note];

    BRMidiNoteName *noteConverter = [[BRMidiNoteName alloc] init];

    NSString *noteName;
    noteName = [noteConverter nameFromNumber:[note intValue] withNotation:[defaults valueForKey:kSettingsNotation]];

   [self.currentNoteLabel performSelectorOnMainThread: @selector( setText: ) withObject: noteName waitUntilDone: NO];

}
```

My code is actually using a dictionary to convert the midi note number to a note name (EG note number 60 = C4).